# Create aggregation tree from individual tree

Tags: javascript, json, sql-server, d3.js, tree

I have a JSON tree that I want to reduce into another "aggregated" tree to combine matching nodes. When combining, nodes that have the same attribute value should be merged into one if their parents have matching attribute values between themselves.

```
Given:
      __ A __
    /    |    \     
   B      B    H
  / \    / \   |
 C   C  C   E  P
/     
Z

Expected:
        A
      /  \
     2B   H    <---for this level, we grouped the B siblings together
    / |   |
  3C  E   P    <---for this level, we grouped the C siblings together and included the C cousin ONLY because their parents were grouped
 /   
Z
```

I tried a combination of D3, Lodash, and plain JS functions but still can't get the correct aggregation tree so my grouping logic must not be right. Here's one of my last attempts with D3's `nest()` function but the results are wrong:

```
d3.nest()
.key( d => d.parent.parent.attribute )   <-- need to group grandparents together by attribute
.key( d => d.parent.attribute )   <-- need to group parents together by attribute
.key( d => d.attribute )    <-- and finally children together by attribute
.rollup( v => v.length )    <-- print how many grand-attribute > parent-attribute > child-attribute sequences were found
.entries( 
         original_tree_flattened.filter( d => (d.depth>=2 && d.depth <= 3 ) <-- has to start with depth 2 in order to reference grandparents. limit to the 3rd level for now.
)
// Note that original_tree_flattened was created via D3's Tree layout function which conveniently builds an array of all the tree nodes with links to parents - https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#_tree
```

Is it best to write out a manual function instead of using utility functions? Also, to note, the original tree data is sitting in a SQL Server database (id, parent, attribute) so if it's easier to aggregate/tackle it via SQL, I'm open to it. Any tips or guidance are appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit 1:** DB looks like:

```
id, parent, attribute
ID1, null, A
ID2, ID1 , B 
ID3, ID1 , B
ID4, ID1 , H
ID5, ID2 , C
ID6, ID2 , C
ID7, ID3 , C
ID8, ID3 , E
ID9, ID4 , P
ID10,ID5 , Z
```

Comment: Seems like you should be able to select distinct on parent and attribute when you make the query.

Comment: Thanks, Mark but the `parent` in the DB represents the individual parent ID so I'm going to get rows for every node in the original tree.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure I understand. In your example above don't you have two rows like `[ID2, Parent:A, Attribute:B, ID2, Parent:A, Attribute:B]`?

Comment: I updated my note with DB info, Mark. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your idea but doing the distinct on parent and attribute would give me:

`parent: null, attribute: A`
`parent: ID1, attribute: B`
`parent: ID1, attribute: H`
`parent: ID2, attribute: C`
...
Not sure how I could generate a tree with that if I need an id, parent pair.

Comment: Did you try to have nested loop of the data as array and achieve that in `O(n^2)` or it too much complexity?

Comment: I started to but I'm trying to leave it as my last resort. The other approach I'm thinking of is to draw out each node's path from root to leaf and then do a distinct on that dataset. I think I can still build a tree from that.